# exporting only rows from sql in phpmyadmin, only where a certain column has Boolean of 0

Tags: sql, excel, phpmyadmin

"meta/background about the use of code and person using it"
 1.site built by professional that left company,
 2.I am inexperienced but trying/ want to learn,
 3.Customer support site for service reps,
................................................
What im trying to do exactly per stackoverflows parameters.
We have a drop down box listing issues that the customer had in a column labeled "issue_type". I can export via csv entire table load onto excel then give to boss for overall review of what the issues were. However data base has a "hide" column. Its function is that when the row is updated the record is kept but the same "job or call" has only one viewable report on site (the most recently updated one). Hide is a boolean. In conclusion I want to export rows that only has the "hide" column Boolean status at 0, AND to only export the columns "customer", and "issue_type". I can seem to only do one or the other. and have researched a minimum of 4 hours to find answer myself and cannot find a syntax to do both at the same time with phpmyadmin. 
I dont want an enormous data that is mostly useless but for issue type and customer but i will have to manually delete all the rows with hide = 1?
Thanks anyone 1st attempt question sorry if not correct for stackflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer,Issue_type FROM tickets where hide =0;
```

Elaborating on what is above for anyone that may be looking for a similar answer, SQL supports the "where" clause of which you can when properly syntaxed select many of your columns and their associated strings, booleans, and numbers to = what your looking for. Wildcards I found later for other uses work as well. 
Sorry about the self answer but hopefully someone finds this usefull